# store jquery data in html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to store the data I get from my `getJSON` in my html element as a list.

here is my script `data.js`:

```
$.getJSON("dataset.json", function(obj) {
    obj.types.forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key.type);
    });
});
```

the console log is a list of keys:

```
one
two
three
four
```

and my html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
        <div class="item-group">
            <label class="item-label">List</label>
                <ul class="list-unstyled" id="dataList"></ul>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I pass the result from getJSON into the `id="dataList"` ?

Comment: You mean you want to create `li` elements containing the text from data, and add these elements to `#dataList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//example data
var data = [{value:'one'},{value:'two'},{value:'three'},{value:'four'}];
data.forEach(function(item){
 $('#dataList').append('<li>'+ item.value +'</li>');
});
//selects the element with id #dataList and adds each value
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
        <div class="item-group">
            <label class="item-label">List</label>
                <ul class="list-unstyled" id="dataList">
                </ul>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of those values and store it with the element using the `data()` method. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("databeta.json", function(obj) {
    $('#dataList').data('types', obj.types.map(function(o) {
        return o.type;
    }));
});
```

Then, when required later in your code you can retrieve that array:

```
var arr = $('#dataList').data('types');
// use arr as needed here...
```